# как проверить функцию на return без ее вызова. PHP

Tags: php

Есть функции в которых содежится оператор echo. И есть функции с echo и return.

Когда строю условие типа if(func() == null). То оно вызывает его и оператор echo что внутри функции срабатывает.

Так вот, как мне узнать есть ли там return, но не запуская саму функцию.

Моя задача такая, у меня в цикле должны отрабатывать функции, с return по первому варианту, а без return по второму варианту.
Но мешает ихний вызов.

Comment: вам самим то не кажется, что такая логика работы неплохо так переступает за грань адекватности кода?

Comment: Да почему бы и нет. Открываете `__FILE__`, делаете синтаксический разбор, находите нужные функции и смотрите есть-ли у них return. Только странная задача сама по себе

Comment: Мне кажется это [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy) Попробуйте сформулировать вопрос шире. Не очень понятно какова ваша цель

Comment: Три развития события, если функция делает возврат то к функции будет подставляться переменная, и брать значение в переменную.
 (Это первое развитие)
---------------------------
Если функция не возвращает значение то, переменную не подставляем. (Второе развитие).
---------------------------
Если функция возвращает значения и при это есть вывод на экран.

Проблема в то, что в логическом файле отрабатывает вывод на экран "echo".

Comment: Так и не нужно все писать. Объясните толком проблему. Про `ob_start()` и прочие `ob_...` функции уже читали?

Comment: @Дмитрий посмотрите [демо-пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3f754dc13dd52a8b921a9e80aace81b9da088931) В результате в массиве $results будут собраны имена функций, у которых в теле есть return.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74317/discussion-on-question-by------return---).